# Como enviar dois valores por parâmetro com uma única opção selecionada? PHP

Tags: php, html, select, value

Preciso enviar dois valores por parâmetro para outra página, porem o campo *value* da tag select só envia um... Como poderia fazer para enviar dois?

Segue o código:

```
<option value="<?php echo $data->format("d/m/Y"); ?>">
     <?php echo $data->format("d/m/Y").' às 14:15'; ?>
</option>
```

Comment: Talvez precise de um atributo `multiple` no select. Pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? dê exemplos pf.

Comment: Por exemplo, estou selecionando aquela opção ali que está mostrando na tela a data e a hora juntas, tipo '01/12/2014 às 14:15', mas no campo value só consigo enviar a data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa é você não especificar o `value`, neste caso será passado o conteúdo de `<option>`, por exemplo:

```
<option>
    <?php echo $data->format("d/m/Y") . ' às 14:15'; ?>
</option>
```

Comment: Assim também não me adianta, pois preciso separar ele na chegada ao destino...

Comment: Você pode separar a data da hora usando `explode('às', $select);` onde `$select` é o nome do `<select>` no `<form>`

Comment: Mas como eu colocaria os dois valores separados na recepção dos arquivos? `$Data = $_POST['slcDataHora'];` e `$Hora = $_POST['slcDataHora'];`?

Comment: Provavelmente assim: `$dados = explode('às', $_POST['slcDataHora']);` então você terá a data em `$dados[0]` e a hora em `$dados[1]`. Mas cuidado com SQL injection, você está usando o `$_POST` sem nenhum tipo de sanitização.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<select name="">
    <option value="{'num_sequence':[0,1,2,3]}">Passando Por Array</option>
    <option value="{'foo':'bar','one':'two'}">Passando por Objeto</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Acho que essa é a melhor solução para meu caso, mas não entendi como funciona... Seria `<option value="{'teste':[<?php echo $data->format("d/m/Y"); ?>, 20:30]}">`? assim não funcionou... Como eu chamo o valor para uma variável, no caso?

Comment: @Alceu neste caso pode usar o objeto, `value="{'dia':'<?php echo $data->format("d/m/Y"); ?>','hora':'20.30'}"` e quando vai buscar o valor ao elemento do DOM tem de usar `JSON.parse(select.value)` para recuperar o objeto. Atenção que deve usar aspas simples no HTML e duplas na string/value para o JSON ser válido.